# Storing BYTE* address in BYTE array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, byte

I have a variable of type `BYTE*`, in which an address from memory is: `BYTE* address = (BYTE*)0x4A4B4C4D` and a `BYTE Array` with 5 digits, where I want to copy the address exactly as it is. `BYTE* jmp = new BYTE[5] {0xE9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}` This array is supposed to represent a 32 bit jump and I have to copy the address to the last 4 digits because it is 4 bytes large. I’ve tried `memcpy` before, but it seems like `memcpy` is only copying the bytes that are at that address in memory and that’s what I don’t want. So my goal is to have a byte array that looks like this: `BYTE[5] {0xE9, 0x4A, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0x4D}`.

Edit:

```
BYTE* jmp = new BYTE[5] {0xE9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

BYTE* address = (BYTE*)0x4A4B4C4D;

memcpy((jmp + 1), &address, 4);

delete[] jmp;
```

Comment: What do you use for your `src` argument to `memcpy`? If you have just `address`, then the behaviour you describe will happen; try using `&address` instead. Difficult to say more from what you've posted.

Comment: Please include your code in your question. It's not very clear what you have tried and failed.

Comment: If you always want to store 5 `BYTE`s, you could use `std::array<BYTE, 5>`

Comment: @AdrianMole For `src` i tried many ways there, including `&address`. But when im doing it that way the array looks like this: `0xE9 0x4D 0xBC 0xA4 0x04`.

Comment: @Christophy Looks like you have an [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issue.

Comment: Also, not sure how you expect to get the `0x4C` byte - did you omit a `4` from `0x4A4BC4D`?

Comment: @AdrianMole Sorry, the `BC` was a mistake. Thats the real address: `0x4A4B4C4D`

Comment: So that means I have a little-endain PC and I have to swap the bytes, am I getting that right?

Answer (score 0):

So there's a couple problems here.
First of all, you are missing a `4` digit in your assignment to address, this is why you get a confusing `0xE9 0x4D 0xBC 0xA4 0x04`

```
BYTE* address = (BYTE*)0x4A4B4C4D;
                             ^
                             this was missing
```

The reason the byte ordering is changed when you do a memcpy is because endianness, read it up:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

In your case, it's little-endian.

Memcpy will just copy the memory content as-is. If you need the `jmp` to order the bytes in a different way, then the only way is to manually copy each byte across:

```
BYTE *ptr_address = (BYTE *)&address;

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
   jmp[1+i] = ptr_address[3-i];
}
```

Comment: Doesn’t`ptr_address` have to be a `BYTE**`?

Comment: I'm also getting an access violation

Comment: No, `ptr_address` doesn't have to be `BYTE**` because you want to treat whatever at the content as a `BYTE` type, because you are copying each individual byte across. Edited my answer to cast `&address` with `(BYTE *)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're very "pointer-heavy".

```
BYTE jmp[5] = {0xE9};
uint32_t address = 0x4A4B4C4D;
memcpy(jmp + 1, &address, 4);
```

or, depending on endianness,

```
BYTE jmp[5] = {0xE9};
uint32_t address = 0x4D4C4B4A;
memcpy(jmp + 1, &address, 4);
```

Comment: I couldn't use that with me like that, because I only have the address the right way around and I'm not allowed to swap it manually.

Comment: @Christophy Weird restrictions and requirements belong in the question.